# Milliseconds in console-stamp don't seem to work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp

I am trying to use console-stamp for logging in node.js, like this:

```
require('console-stamp')(console, {
    datePrefix:'',
    dateSuffix: '',
    pattern: 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss.l'
});
var log = {
        info: function (info) {
            console.info(info);
        },
        warning:function (warning) {
            console.warn(warning);
        },
        error:function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        },
        debug:function (debug) {
            console.log(debug);
        }
};
module.exports = log
```

However, what I see is that the milliseconds value grows in the logs across second boundaries, like this:

```
24/10/2018 12:21:40.673 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:21:40.675 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:21:45.680 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:21:45.688 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:21:50.692 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:21:50.694 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:21:55.699 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:21:55.702 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:22:00.706 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:22:00.707 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:22:05.711 [LOG]    log
24/10/2018 12:22:05.715 [LOG]    log
```

Then the "milliseconds" value gets to 999 and restarts from 0.

"l" is the right format for the milliseconds according to https://github.com/starak/node-console-stamp, which links to http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format. I also tried using "L" and even manually printing getMilliseconds() of a new Date, like this:

```
debug: function (debug) {
   var currentTime = new Date();
   var ms = currentTime.getMilliseconds();
   console.log(ms + " !!!! " + debug);
}
```

I still get a value that grows through the logs.

Has anyone seen this happening? Do you know how to get a sensible milliseconds value?

Comment: `grows through the logs` what do you mean by this? There are `1000` milliseconds in a second, so the value goes from `0` to `999` and back to `0`

Comment: @mark I think they mean that they're weirdly consecutive. If you look at the log they look sorted, in a way. Which probably means nothing, per se, and may just be a weird coincidence.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I see it now, that's really odd.

Comment: @monday-to-friday Is this the case for the entire log file?

Comment: @Mark yes, the whole log just carries on like this. Gets to 999 (roughly) and then starts from 0 (roughly).

Comment: @Frederico klez Culloca it really isn't just a coincidence - it carries on like this for ages.

Comment: I suggest you ask the library maintainer, because this looks more like a bug than a problem with your code.

Comment: Do you call these functions in `setInterval`/`setTimeout` callback?

Comment: @barbsan yes, they get called every 5 seconds. Does this explain anything?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca but I get the same result with printing out a value of milliseconds for a freshly created Date object :( which means this isn't just a problem with this specific library, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing your messages in a pattern, probably using a `setInterval` as you mention in the comments.

You first print 2 consecutive log messages, then wait 5 seconds and print 2 new messages. Because of this the milliseconds will display in an ascending pattern. 
After you print the first message, it takes 2 milliseconds for the next function to execute, so your next timestamp will be `milliseconds+2`, then you wait 5 seconds and 5 more milliseconds for the execution time (which can vary slightly), so the next timestamp is `milliseconds + 2 + 5000 + 5`....and so on.

There is nothing wrong with the library or your code.